# get image height with jquery in chrome

Tags: jquery, image, google-chrome, height

I have this problem: i am trying to get the height of few images inside a div but i'm having problems with Chrome. All my attempts either return 0 or NaN.. here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="mid">
    <div class="cimglist">
        <a href="#"><img src="img1.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img2.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img3.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img4.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img5.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
var CardsTotalImages = 0;
var CardsCurrentImage = 0;
var CardsHeights = [];

$('.cimglist img').each(function() {
    /*
    CardsHeights[CardsCurrentImage] = $(this).height(); 
    CardsCurrentImage++;
    //this works great on IE and FF
    */
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload(function() {
        CardsHeights[CardsCurrentImage] = parseInt($(this).height());
        CardsCurrentImage++;
    });
    img.src = $(this).attr('src');
});
```

I've searched around every post to find a solution but the only helpful info i got is that, Chrome must load the images in the first hand, and then get the heights.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your `img.onload` use:

```
var h = $(this).get(0).height; // height
var w = $(this).get(0).width; // width
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope all of these things are within a `$(document).ready(function () { });` ?

If so, there is no reason chrome wouldn't be able to grab `$(this).height()` from the images. You won't need the `img.onload` that way

On a side note, try not to name **variables** in JS with Capital names, unless they are Classes / Instsantiable objects

Comment: Any specific reason why camelcase should be banned from variable names, dying to know ?

Comment: Coding conventions may vary from case to case. I think "never" comes a bit strong here.

Comment: Touche :) Changed it to say you shouldn't use it. It's just a very common coding convention, it allows other developers to know when you need to instantiate `new WhateverThing()`. Thousands of lines of code everything in Camel would be absurd

Comment: Yes mcpDESIGNS, all these are inside $(document).ready() The strange thing is that, if i use $(window).load instead, chrome is able to get correctly the heights of the images. Another thing i noticed is that the img.onload() doesn't seem to work inside $.each(). The script just freezes completely.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery all the way?

```
var CardsTotalImages = 0;
var CardsCurrentImage = 0;
var CardsHeights = [];

$('.cimglist').on('load', 'img', function() {
    CardsHeights[CardsCurrentImage] = $(this).height() || this.height; // added an alternative just in case. i've seen firefox do strange things during my time as a front-end developer.
    CardsCurrentImage++;
});
```

**EDIT:**

This code should run before the `img` elements are rendered.

Comment: cause it just does'nt work the same way if the image is cached?

Comment: In specific cases. If the image is cached in the browser but the element hasn't loaded yet this should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution, hope it helps.
I have set the dimensions of the images in the img tag and it worked also for Chrome.
Say:

```
<img width="464" height="287" src="myimg.jpg">
```